# ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!

Tags: ros, turtlebot, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to set up a turtle bot for the past couple days. So I went through the instructions found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup#Workstation_Setup) and made it up to 5.4; when i typed in "rostopic list" into the workstation, it is unable to communicate with master.

**ON WORKSTATION**

echo $ROS_MASTER_URI

http://192.168.1.101:11311

echo $ROS_HOSTNAME

192.168.1.100

**ON LAPTOP**

echo $ROS_MASTER_URI

http://192.168.1.100:11311

echo $ROS_HOSTNAME

192.168.1.101

**Laptop IP=**192.168.1.101
**Workstation IP=**192.168.1.100

Any help with resolving this issue would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40762/error:-unable-to-communicate-with-master!/) by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on 2012-08-07**:
thanks, i changed the ROS_MASTER_URI as you said, but it is still unable to contact master. Any other ideas?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-07**:
Is the robot running? Did you start roscore? And don't set ROS_HOSTNAME to an ip address. Instead, use the variable ROS_IP.

**Comment by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on 2012-08-07**:
when i start roscore i get WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI [http://192.168.1.101:11311] host is not set to this machine

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-07**:
Did you set ROS_IP and unset ROS_HOSTNAME?

**Comment by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on 2012-08-07**:
i set up the ROS_IP; how do I unset the ROS_HOSTNAME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There will only be a single ROS master between the 2 machines, which by the given instructions should be on the turtlebot laptop. You should change your ~/.bashrc file on the laptop from:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.100:11311
```

to:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.101:11311
```

This assumes that your laptop has the IP 192.168.1.101 and your workstation has the IP 192.168.1.100

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7